# Hide 2022 Parent Theme Templates / Parts

Tags: theme-development

I'm playing with the new FSE and 2022 theme. I made a child theme and know how to create my own custom template/block parts but how can I hide the parent theme template I don't wish to use like `templates/page-large-header.html`?

Is there a way to do this without modifying the parent theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, after doing a ton of research and reading around, unregistering parent theme templates/parts like you can with blocks isn't possible. You can only copy files into the child theme and override. There is no way to hide unused parent theme template parts as I write this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this situation is via child-template overwrite.

Since you already have a child theme (which is good), you only need to overwrite the according parts, in your case - the header template.

Now - first you need to find out which template file you want to overwrite, because a header template may consist of several smaller child templates too.

Best way to do this in my opinion is to use "What the file", small plugin which will show some template info in the upper right corner on the frontend (which file to overwrite).

Then, create a new file with the same name, which will overrule the parent template/template-part.

Leave that file empty (e.g. header.php), or return something else at that place/in that file as you wish. This is a simple template overwrite.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't hide it from the end-user and can still be applied. My goal is to hide unused parent templates/template parts... I know how to override them.

Comment: Then simply do a return false? Display: none? THIS is the proper way of doing such things. Whatever..

Answer (score 0):

I've found a reasonably good solution for **hiding custom templates**, but not for hiding template parts. Here's the one that works for templates and you can read more about it in detail in my question at the link [Unload templates; disable parent Template Parts using only "theme.json"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/416459/74876) where I explained everything in more detail.

Here's my hack :) - It really does work.

```json
{
  "name": "no-title",
  "title": "Successfully removed",
  "postTypes": [
    "to-remove-parent-template-use-dummy-post-type"
  ]
},
```

Comment: And... no. My "solution" is partially working. In other words, users don't see the custom templates when they enter a post, but they're still visible in the 'Site edit' section.